# How to actually-really-copy a file to an ext4 pendrive using dolphin?

Tags: usb, dolphin

Dolphin is lying to me.

When I copy some files to a pendrive, it happens far too fast. Suspiciously fast to actually be doing something.

When I initially read the just-copied files, I do get the actual file contents. However, unmount the drive, disconnect it from the machine, reinsert it, remount it, and the result is a bunch of file corruption.

When unmounting, I use the dolphin menu to unmount. It appears to unmount partially. While the drive is no longer unmountable or accessible, it does stay in the dolphin menu.

I notice that a lot of the time, exactly 1.8GB is copied.

I tested various file systems. EXT suffers from corruption. The files are copied far too quickly, and the drive won't properly un-mount. NTFS also has these problems. Unfortunately I could not test NTFS much; mkfs.ntfs is currently broken and hangs forever.

FAT32, however, works. I can copy some files, remove the drive, reinsert it, then read them back. Obviously, this is a problem. FAT32 is awful. It doesn't properly support unicode filenames or large files.

Some other observations: 
1. The disk, when forcibly removed without unmounting when unmount hangs, will do various things;

a) Corrupt completely (ntfs). Only reformatting saves it.

b) Corrupt partially (ntfs). Parts of filenames are replaced with random garbage bytes. Only 1.8G is actually on the disk.

c) Only have part of the files on the disk. Some multiple of 4MiB, usually totalling 1.8GB. Interestingly, the "parts" are usually not sequential; i.e. of the total say 3.5GiB copied, 1.4GiB is present on the drive, random 4MiB chunks from various files. (ext4)

d) Copy very fast, and have complete files on the disk (ext4) but, when reinserted into the system, the drive is rather in state (c).

Some other strangeness:

1. When I use ext4, and place my copied files in a sub-folder of the pendrive, accessing that subfolder in a terminal works... but using 'ls' will hang inside the kernel.

Note: everything seems to function using FAT.

My reaction to all of this is just one giant 'wat?'... I'm very confused. I just want to copy some files, this shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: You said you unmounted the device. How do you do that? Did you right click on drive and use the "Safely Remove" menu entry in Dolphin, or some other method? If the unmount hangs, are you sure it hangs forever? Writing cached data to the disk can take a long time.

Comment: You could use iostat (eg iostat -k 5 ) to see when and how much data is written to the device.